# Transição de CSS ignorada quando a ordem da array no v-for muda

Tags: css, vue.js, css-transições

Estou a fazer um componente onde posso arrastar outros componentes na vertical. Quando um componente passar pelo outro eles devem trocar de lugar (no eixo X).

O que acontece é que o elemento que estou a arrastar respeita a transição de CSS, desliza para a proxima posição, mas o outro não. Ele salta diretamente para a nova posição.

Qual a razão disto acontecer e como corrigir?

```js
Vue.component('dragable', {
    props:  ['config', 'leftPosition'],
    template: '#dragable',
    data() {
        return {
            elementStartCoords: null,
            pointerTouchDown: null,
            pointerUpHandler: this.onPointerUp.bind(this),
            pointerMoveHandler: this.onPointerMove.bind(this)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        style() {
            return {
                top: this.config.top + 'px',
                left: this.leftPosition * 150 + 'px'
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getPointerCoordinates(e) {
                return {
                    y: e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY
                };
            },
            getElementPosition(el) {
                const coords = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                return {
                    y: coords.top
                };
            },

            onPointerDown(e) {
                this.elementStartCoords = this.getElementPosition(this.$el);
                this.pointerTouchDown = this.getPointerCoordinates(e);

                window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.pointerUpHandler);
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.pointerMoveHandler);
            },
            onPointerMove(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (!this.pointerTouchDown) return;

                const pointerPosition = this.getPointerCoordinates(e);
                const yDiff = pointerPosition.y - this.pointerTouchDown.y;

                this.$emit('dragevent', {
                    name: this.config.name,
                    top: this.elementStartCoords.y + yDiff
                });
            },
            onPointerUp() {
                window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.pointerUpHandler);
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.pointerMoveHandler);

                // reset used variables
                this.pointerTouchDown = null;
                this.elementStartCoords = null;
            },
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            draggables: [{
                name: 'A',
                top: 70
            }, {
                name: 'B',
                top: 0
            }]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleDrag(config) {
            const draggable = this.draggables.find(drg => drg.name == config.name);
            draggable.top = config.top;
            this.draggables = this.draggables.sort((a, b) => b.top - a.top);
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.dragable {
 user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #dde;
    border: 2px solid #88A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: left 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <p>Dragable test</p>
    <template v-for="(draggable, i) in draggables">
        <dragable :key="draggable.name" :config="draggable" :left-position="i" @dragevent="handleDrag"></dragable>
    </template>
</div>

<template lang="html" id="dragable">
    <div class="dragable" :style="style" @mousedown="onPointerDown" draggable="false">{{'Draggable ' + config.name}}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema que havia era que o `.sort()` estava a mudar a posição dos elemento no `v-for` e isso fazia com que o Vue pensasse que se tratava de novos elementos. Configurando a posição à esquerda de outra maneira resolve o problema:

```js
Vue.component('dragable', {
  props: ['config', 'leftPosition'],
  template: '#dragable',
  data() {
    return {
      elementStartCoords: null,
      pointerTouchDown: null,
      pointerUpHandler: this.onPointerUp.bind(this),
      pointerMoveHandler: this.onPointerMove.bind(this)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    style() {
      return {
        top: this.config.top + 'px',
        left: this.leftPosition * 150 + 'px'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPointerCoordinates(e) {
      return {
        y: e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY
      };
    },
    getElementPosition(el) {
      const coords = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        y: coords.top
      };
    },

    onPointerDown(e) {
      this.elementStartCoords = this.getElementPosition(this.$el);
      this.pointerTouchDown = this.getPointerCoordinates(e);

      window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.pointerUpHandler);
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.pointerMoveHandler);
    },
    onPointerMove(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (!this.pointerTouchDown) return;

      const pointerPosition = this.getPointerCoordinates(e);
      const yDiff = pointerPosition.y - this.pointerTouchDown.y;

      this.$emit('dragevent', {
        name: this.config.name,
        top: this.elementStartCoords.y + yDiff
      });
    },
    onPointerUp() {
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.pointerUpHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.pointerMoveHandler);

      // reset used variables
      this.pointerTouchDown = null;
      this.elementStartCoords = null;
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      draggables: [{
        name: 'A',
        top: 70,
        left: 0
      }, {
        name: 'B',
        top: 0,
        left: 1
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleDrag(config) {
      const draggable = this.draggables.find(drg => drg.name == config.name);
      draggable.top = config.top;
      const positions = this.draggables.slice().sort((a, b) => b.top - a.top).reduce((obj, drg, i) => (obj[drg.name] = i, obj), {});
      this.draggables = this.draggables.map(drg => {
        return {
          ...drg,
          left: positions[drg.name]
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dragable {
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #dde;
  border: 2px solid #88A;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Dragable test</p>
  <template v-for="draggable in draggables">
        <dragable :key="draggable.name" :config="draggable" :left-position="draggable.left" @dragevent="handleDrag"></dragable>
    </template>
</div>

<template lang="html" id="dragable">
    <div class="dragable" :style="style" @mousedown="onPointerDown" draggable="false">{{'Draggable ' + config.name}}</div>
</template>
```